# Adding a Database Entry in a Pseudo-Element operation in Joomla

Tags: css, joomla, pseudo-element

I am using a template for Joomla called JA Fixel, and the homepage is composed of grids. The website can be seen here: http://develop.rushsoccer.com

After x articles, I have a button to show more articles. Once I click this button, I would like all articles to show their published date below the grid box they take up (this is easier to explain if you take a look at the link).

I have seen the template gives the html for the grid box of this:

```
<div class="items front-page-stories rotateX social grid-1x1" style="width: 198px; height: 198px; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 792px;">
```

I have made CSS of this code

`.items.front-page-stories.rotateX.social.grid-1x1::after {
    content:"Office: XXXXX \A Mobile: YYYYY ";
    white-space:pre;
    }`

to see if I can at least get some content to show, however I do not see anything show up. I just assumed that I could solve this with a pseudo-class element? If I can get this to work, I will edit the content to grab the article date from php, but I would like to see some content show up first.

Does anybody have any suggestions?
Thanks!

Comment: I forgot to mention that this code does seem to work in a jsfiddle to show the code, however, this will not work inside the JA Fixel template. Perhaps no one will know how to solve this then because of this, but any suggestions I am open to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just miss the `position:absolute`.
Try this:

```
.items.front-page-stories.rotateX.social.grid-1x1::after {
    content:"Office: XXXXX \A Mobile: YYYYY";
    position: absolute;
    white-space:pre;
}
```

Comment: I am now able to see the text because of that position: absolute.